# how do i return a boolean from a json nested object

Tags: json, reactjs, object, nested, boolean

Why am i getting

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"

when trying to get this nested Object?

Json..

```
  "controlPanel" : [
      "mainsStatus": {
        "mainsOn": false,
        "offlineDateTime": "2019-09-03T16:42:15.181819"
      }
]


<tr>
<th><LocalizedMessage of="mainsStatus" /></th>
<td>
<div>{controlPanels.mainsStatus ? controlPanels.mainsStatus.mainsOn : "" === true ? 'Mains On' : 'Mains Off'}
</div>
<div>Offline Date: <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{controlPanels.mainsStatus ? controlPanels.mainsStatus.offlineDateTime : ""}
</Moment>
</div>
</td>
<td><Badge className="large" variant="success">Passed</Badge></td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
```

I do this on nested array for boolean and it works fine..

```
{controlPanels.areaStatuses && controlPanels.areaStatuses.map((aS, id) => (
<div>
<span>ID: {aS.areaId}</span>
<span>{aS.armed === true ? 'Armed' : 'Disarmed'}</span>
<span>{aS.inAlarm === true ? 'InAlarm' : 'OffAlarm'}</span>
</div>
))}
```

Comment: Please show your full component

Comment: ...and valid JSON. JSON cannot start with a property name.

Comment: have updated. this is just a question about returning true of false from the nested object. all other code isnt related. {controlPanels.mainsStatus ? controlPanels.mainsStatus.mainsOn : "" === true ? 'Mains On' : 'Mains Off'}

Comment: Ive added an example of how I do this for nested array which works, its the nested 'object' which throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

its ok I fixed it. should have been {controlPanels.mainsStatus ? controlPanels.mainsStatus.mainsOn === true ? 'Mains On' : 'Mains Off' : "" }